# Testing unlinked YouTube accounts

Tags: youtube-api

My app authenticates with YouTube to get a user's favorites list. I need to handle the case of unlinked YouTube accounts, but my accounts were all created after 2009 (so they're linked). Has anyone found a way to create an unlinked account to use for testing?

Comment: I don't think it's possible ... hence why I kept an unlinked account for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just create a Google account. That account is unlinked to Youtube unless you sign in youtube with it.